# Firing Vuex actions asynchronously and sequentially - what am I not understanding?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, vuex

I have a Vuex store and I am trying to fetch data from the Firebase Realtime Database. I am initially fetching the user information, however afterwards I would like to fetch some other information that relies upon the initial data fetched.

As you can see from the code, I am trying to do this using async / await, however whenever firing the two actions in my `created()` hook, the user's information isn't initialised, and therefore the second action fails.

**My user store**

```
    async fetchCreds({ commit }) {
        try {
            firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async function(user) {
                const { uid } = user
                const userDoc = await users.doc(uid).get()

                return commit('SET_USER', userDoc.data())
            })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            commit('SET_USER', {})
        }
    }
```

**My club action which relies upon the above call**

```
    async fetchClubInformation({ commit, rootState }) {
        try {
            const clubIDForLoggedInUser = rootState.user.clubId
            const clubDoc = await clubs.doc(clubIDForLoggedInUser).get()

            return commit('SET_CLUB_INFO', clubDoc.data())
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
}
```

**The methods being called within my component's created() method.**

```
  created: async function() {
        await this.fetchCreds();
        await this.fetchClubInformation();
        this.loading = false;
  }
```

I have a feeling I'm fundamentally misunderstanding async / await, but I can't understand what in the code is incorrect - any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What result are you getting? Any errors in the browser console? What does the network console show in terms of the requests? What does the Vue plugin for chrome show in the Vuex tab?

Comment: Also, can you show how you've mapped the actions?

Comment: Apologies, I should have included more info initially. The error I get is one from Firebase, however it is related to the fact that the variable I'm passing as the ID of the document is undefined, even though I've just set it using the initial action. In terms of how I'm mapping the actions, I'm utilising Vue's mapActions method and then calling them as above in the created() hook.

Comment: fetchcreds returns undefined - nothing to await to resolve

Comment: @Estradiaz So if I simply return something underneath the try catch statement, the call will work as expected?

Comment: Yes - return an awaitable promise - eg  return new promise ... resolve(commit  ...

Comment: If the method declaration is set to async already, won't it wrap whatever I return in a promise anyway? If my understanding is correct, which it may not be and probably isn't, the return statement under the try catch will only be executed after all of the above data from Firebase has loaded, so if I were to return '1' would that suffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not particularly familiar with Firebase but after a bit of digging through the source code I think I can shed a little light on your problems.

Firstly, consider the following example:

```js
async function myFn (obj) {
  obj.method(function () {
    console.log('here 1')
  })

  console.log('here 2')
}

await myFn(x)
console.log('here 3')
```

Question: What order will you see the log messages?

Well `here 2` will definitely come before `here 3` but it's impossible to tell from the code above when `here 1` will show up. It depends on what `obj.method` does with the function it's been passed. It might never call it at all. It might call it synchronously (e.g. Array's `forEach` method), in which case `here 1` will appear before the other messages. If it's asynchronous (e.g. timers, server calls) then `here 1` may not show up for some time, long after `here 3`.

The `async` modifier will implicitly return a Promise from the function if it doesn't return a Promise itself. The resolved value of that Promise will be the value returned from the function and **the Promise will resolve at the point the function returns**. For a function without a `return` at the end that's equivalent to it finishing with `return undefined`.

So, to stress the key point, the Promise returned by an async function will only wait until that function returns.

The method `onAuthStateChanged` calls its callback asynchronously, so the code in that callback won't run until after the surrounding function has completed. There's nothing to tell the implicitly returned Promise to wait for that callback to be invoked. The `await` inside the callback is irrelevant as that function hasn't even been called yet.

Firebase makes extensive use of Promises, so typically the solution would just be to `return` or `await` the relevant Promise:

```js
// Note: This WON'T work, explanation follows
return firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async function(user) {
```

```js
// Note: This WON'T work, explanation follows
await firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async function(user) {
```

This won't work here because `onAuthStateChanged` doesn't actually return a Promise, it returns an `unsubscribe` function.

You could, of course, create a new Promise yourself and 'fix' it that way. However, creating new Promises using `new Promise` is generally considered a code smell. Typically it's only necessary when wrapping code that doesn't support Promises properly. If we're working with a library that has proper Promise support (as we are here) then we shouldn't need to create any Promises.

So why doesn't `onAuthStateChanged` return a Promise?

Because it's a way of watching all sign-in/sign-out events. Every time the user signs in or signs out it'll call the callback. It isn't intended as a way to watch a particular sign-in. A Promise can only be resolved once, to a single value. So while a single sign-in event could be modelled with a Promise it's meaningless when watching all sign-in/sign-out events.

So `fetchCreds` is registering to be notified about all sign-in/sign-out events. It doesn't do anything with the returned `unsubscribe` function, so presumably it'll be listening to all such events until the page is reloaded. If you call `fetchCreds` multiple times it'll keep adding more and more listeners.

If you're waiting for a user to finish signing in then I suggest waiting for that directly instead. `firebase.auth()` has various methods starting with the prefix `signIn`, e.g. `signInWithEmailAndPassword`, and these do return a Promise that resolves when the user has finished signing in. The resolved value provides access to various information, including the user. I don't know which method you're using but the idea is much the same for all of them.

However, it might be that you're really just interested in grabbing the details of the current user. If that's all you want then you don't need to use `onAuthStateChanged` at all. You should just be able to grab a copy using the `currentUser` property. Something like this:

```js
async fetchCreds({ commit }) {
   try {
      const { uid } = firebase.auth().currentUser
      const userDoc = await users.doc(uid).get()

      commit('SET_USER', userDoc.data())
   } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      commit('SET_USER', {})
   }
}
```

As I've already mentioned, this relies on the assumption that the user is already signed in. If that isn't a safe assumption then you might want to consider waiting until after sign in has completed before creating components that need user credentials.

**Update:**

Questions from the comments:

> If the obj.method() call was asynchronous and we did await the callback function within it, would that ensure that the outer async function (myFn) never resolves before the inner one has finished?

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here.

Just to be clear, I'm being very careful with my use of the words `async` and *asynchronous*. A function such as `setTimeout` would be considered *asynchronous* but it is not `async`.

`async`/`await` is just a lot of syntactic sugar around Promises. You don't really wait for a function, you wait for a Promise. When we talk about awaiting an `async` function we're really talking about waiting for the Promise it returns to resolve.

So when you say *await the callback function* it's not really clear what that means. Which Promise are you trying to `await`?

Putting the `async` modifier on a function doesn't make it magically wait for things. It will only wait when it encounters `await`. You can still have other asynchronous calls within an `async` function and, just like with a normal function, these calls will be performed after the function has returned. The only way to 'pause' is to `await` a Promise.

Putting an `await` inside another function, even a nested function, won't make any difference to whether the outer function waits unless the outer function is already waiting for the inner function. Behind the scenes this is all just Promises chaining `then` calls. Whenever you write `await` you're just adding another `then` call to a Promise. However, that won't have the desired effect unless that Promise is in the same chain as the Promise returned by the outer `async` function. It only needs one link to be missing for the chain to fail.

So modifying my earlier example:

```js
async function myFn (obj) {
  await obj.method(async function () {
    await somePromise

    // ...
  })

  // ...
}

await myFn(x)
```

Note that there are 3 functions here: `myFn`, `method` and the callback passed to `method`. The question is, will `await myFn(x)` wait for `somePromise`?

From the code above we can't actually tell. It would depend on what `method` does internally. For example, if `method` looked like this then it still wouldn't work:

```js
function method (callback) {
  setTimeout(callback, 1000)
}
```

Putting `async` on `method` won't help, that'll just make it return a Promise but the Promise still won't be waiting for the timer to fire.

Our Promise chain has a broken link. `myFn` and the callback are both creating their parts of the chain but unless `method` links those Promises together it won't work.

On the other hand, if `method` is written to return a suitable Promise that waits for the callback to complete then we will get our target behaviour:

```js
function method (callback) {
  return someServerCallThatReturnsAPromise().then(callback)
}
```

We could have used `async`/`await` here instead but there was no need as we can just return the Promise directly.

> Also, if in the async myFn function you're not returning anything, does that mean it'll resolve immediately and as undefined?

The term *immediately* is not well-defined here.

1. If a function isn't returning anything at the end then it's equivalent to having `return undefined` at the end.
2. The Promise returned by an `async` function will resolve at the point the function returns.
3. The resolved value for the Promise will be the value returned.

So if you aren't returning anything it will resolve to `undefined`. Resolving won't happen until the end of the function is reached. If the function doesn't contain any `await` calls then this will happen 'immediately' in the same sense as a synchronous function returning 'immediately'.

However, `await` is just syntactic sugar around a `then` call, and `then` calls are always asynchronous. So while the Promise might *resolve* 'immediately' the `await` still has to wait. It's a very short wait, but it isn't synchronous and other code may get the opportunity to run in the meantime.

Consider the following:

```js
const myFn = async function () {
  console.log('here 3')
}

console.log('here 1')

Promise.resolve('hi').then(() => {
  console.log('here 4')
})

console.log('here 2')

await myFn()

console.log('here 5')
```

The log messages will appear in the order they're numbered. So even though `myFn` resolves 'immediately' you'll still get `here 4` jumping in between `here 3` and `here 5`.

Comment: Thank you very, very much for your detailed answer, it's really helped me understand things clearer and I appreciate you taking the time to go into so much depth. One question I do have though, is that if the obj.method() call was asynchronous and we did await the callback function within it, would that ensure that the outer async function (myFn) never resolves before the inner one has finished? Also, if in the async myFn function you're not returning anything, does that mean it'll resolve immediately and as undefined? Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: @Joshua I've added a new section to the end to address your questions. I suggest playing around with some simple examples yourself to help refine your understanding. Then read the MDN introductions to Promises and `async`/`await`. Even if you've read them before, read them again. It takes a few iterations before it sinks in.

Comment: Thank you. That clears things up quite a bit. I think I still need to spend a few hours getting to grips with it, but as you say, fiddling with the code should help with that. Thanks again for the in-depth answer. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

To make it short

```
fetchCreds({ commit }) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async function(user) {
            const { uid } = user
            const userDoc = await users.doc(uid).get()

            commit('SET_USER', userDoc.data())
            resolve()
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        commit('SET_USER', {})
        resolve()
    }}
}
```

---

```
async () => undefined // returns Promise<undefined> -> undefined resolves immediatly

asnyc () => func(cb) // returns Promise<any> resolves before callback got called

() => new Promise(resolve => func(() => resolve())) // resolves after callback got called
```